# Selecting image error using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a basic c# test below. My test is essentially going to go onto www.asos.com then search for a specific item. When the search results are loaded I want to click on the first item that's returned. I tried to use CSS selector to click on the first imagine but I get an exception. Invalid selector.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;


namespace Exercise1
{
    class Exercise_2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@data-testid='search-input']")).SendKeys("Polo Ralph Lauren Oxford Shirt In Regular Fit Blue");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='search-button-inline']")).Click();
            //*[@id="product-6153807"]/a/div[1]/img Xpath of the image to be clicked on
            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("6153807")).Click();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following css selector.

```
article img
```

in code,

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article img")).Click();
```

Comment: by inspect, article is parent tag of img. please accept my answer.

Comment: When I inspect I don't see article anywhere as the parent tag

Comment: I am able to see. not a immediate parent. ancestor/great grand parent. (article -> a ->div ->img)